# Add Object to Array of Objects in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

There is an array of objects and to add object to it i tries the following:

```
Shape ShapeList[30];

void addShape(Shape s)
{
  for(int i=0; i<30;i++)
  {
    if(ShapeList[i] != '\0')
        { i++;}
    else
        {
            ShapeList[i]=s;
            numShapes++;
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

**numShapes** is an integer variable, Shape is the class and **ShapeList is the array of objects**. But the compiler gives an error in this way that `!=` operator is not allowed. So how can i implement this?

Comment: ShapeList is a class like Shape? If so you should be calling the instance of ShapeList, not the class name.

Comment: ShapeList is the array of objects

Comment: @user I seriously doubt that the answer you’ve accepted is actually going to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to change your 'container' declaration:

```
Shape *ShapeList[30];

void addShape(Shape *s)
{
  for(int i=0; i<30;i++)
  {
    if(ShapeList[i])
        { i++;}
    else
        {
            ShapeList[i]=s;
            numShapes++;
            break;
        }
   }
}
```

and call addShape this way:

```
addShape(new Shape());
```

Comment: Note that while this answer fixes the obvious problems in the code, it’s still not good code. In particular, it’s prone to memory leaks. C++ offers superior mechanisms for this.

Comment: @ konradrudolph can u suggest any other mechanism

Comment: @user It really depends on the specific scenario but if you don’t require polymorphism, then don’t use pointers at all; store the objects directly. Otherwise, one simple general-purpose solution is to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers, and either a `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of the array.

Comment: I keep the answer most simple possible, because the theme of proper memory handling is worth much more questions/answers :)

Answer (score 2):

`ShapeList[i]` returns an object of type `Shape`. In that case, you can overload `operator != (char)`.

```
class Shape
{
//your implementation
//
public:
   bool operator != (char x) const
   {
     // comparison logic
   }
};
```

Also, I believe you have a mistake here:

```
if(ShapeList[i] != '\0')
    { i++;}
```

I assume you want to skip this case, but you already increment `i` in the `for` loop. You probably want:

```
if(ShapeList[i] != '\0')
    { continue;}
```

As others have pointed out, you should use a `std::vector` instead of a raw array. I initially assumed `ShapeList` was a wrapper over a `std` container.

Comment: you havent added the object to array

Comment: This answer is seriously confused. You might get the code to compile like this but it’s **certainly** not what the OP wants.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was assuming he wanted to compare a `Shape` with a `char`.

Comment: @Luchian Obviously. But I doubt that that’s the case, otherwise the question would have been completely different. My guess is that chac’s answer is more or less right (but his minimal fix isn’t a good solution to the problem either).

Comment: @KonradRudolph might be, if that is indeed what the op wants to do. We can just assume.

Answer (score 1):

```
Shape * ShapeList[30];   
  numShapes=0;   

     void addShape(Shape* s)
        {
            if( i>=30)
                return;
            ShapeList[numShapes++]=s;      // provided you need to insert at end
        }
```

You can't use `\0` because it's an array, not a string.

storing the whole object as such is an overhead with memory. pointers are a better choice unless you have local variables going out of scope problems. and if STL and Vectors is not beyond your scope of the project you are on to try using it. in which you can use pushback() or pushfront()

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: do you find any problem with this?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: he want to implement an array of objects. and this does solve it

Comment: @user- storing the whole object as such is an overhead with memory. pointers are a better choice unless you have local variables going out of scope problems. and if STL and Vectors is not beyond your scope of the project you are on to try using it. in which you can use pushback() or pushfront()

Comment: @CodingMastero: If you want to add something to your answer, edit your answer. Don't make it a comment. Specifically, your suggestion about using the STL should be an edit, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a conversion operator in the `Shape` class to convert it to a character, or a not-equal comparison operator that takes a character as argument, you can not compare a `Shape` object to a `char` like you do.

You should be using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and use the `at` member function to see if entry exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how `ShapeList` is declared.

With the != operator you compare it to the character NUL,
while 4 lines below you assign it a Shape object.

What i think you are trying to achieve, is: find an empty slot in the array of pointers to Shape, and store the Shape there.

But probably better is to use either a std::vector, or std::list, and push_back your shape.

Another thing you have to ask yourself: do i want to store copies of my Shape object, or pointers?