# C++ Placing objects in arrays

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am **trying to place objects in an array list** and **3 errors** popped up. I looked into the forums and there's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375125/add-object-to-array-of-objects-in-c) similar to mine but I don't think it's applicable in my case. 
Here's my code:

in test.cpp (main file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "House.h"
using namespace std;

House HouseArray[2];

int main()
{
    string toPrint;
    House Kubo("Kubo", 2);
    HouseArray[0] = Kubo;
    toPrint = HouseArray[0].GetHouseName;
    cout <<toPrint<< endl;

}
```

in House.cpp

```
#include "House.h"
#include <iostream>


House::House(string a, int h)
{
    Name = a;
    Health = h;
}
void House::DamageHouse(int d) {
    Health -= d;
    cout << "Your " << Name << " has " << Health << " left."<<endl;
}
int House::GetHouseHealth() {
    return Health;
}
string House::GetHouseName() {
    string returning = Name;
    return returning;
}
House::~House()
{
}
```

in House.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class House
{
    string Name;
    int Health;
public:
    House(string a, int h);
    int GetHouseHealth();
    void DamageHouse(int d);
    string GetHouseName();
    ~House();
};
```

Errors:

1. Error C2512 'House': no appropriate default constructor available test.cpp in line 9
2. Error C3867 'House::GetHouseName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to
   create a pointer to
   member test.cpp in line 16
3. Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand
   operand of type 'overloaded-function' (or there is no acceptable
   conversion) test.cpp in line 16

Comment: Do you intend to ***call*** the `GetHouseName` member function? And when you create an array of objects, the elements in the array will be default constructed and you don't have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need a default constructor if you want to create an array like that: `House HouseArray[2];` The compiler will need to know how to create an empty `House` so that the initial array can be initialised. Thus add something like the following to House.h

   `House() {
       Name = "";
       Health = 0;
   }`
2. To call a function on a class, you need to add the braces:
   `toPrint = HouseArray[0].GetHouseName();`
3. I suspect that the above will solve this issue as well.

Comment: What is `a` and `h` in your default ctor?

Comment: The elements of the array are value initialized because it has static storage duration (because it's defined at namespace scope). Making it a local variable makes the problem go away.

Comment: @acraig5075, sorry, forgot to fix that part when copying the code, fixed now: it should be some valid default values

Comment: `std::string` already has default initializaation, it is a waste of time to do `Name = "";`